# How to sort a Multidimensional using the second value

Tags: python, sorting

Say if you have a list like this:

```
List = [["james",3],["harry",1],["Joe",2]]
```

How would you sort it so that it sorts the list by the numbers instead of the names? i want it to produce this:

```
List = [["harry",1],["Joe",2],["james",3]]
```

What i'm currently doing:

```
List.sort(key=List[1])
```

Not sure why this doesnt work though? The website im using to learn this isnt very clear at all really.

Comment: just do `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`, key needs to be a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

`x` here refers to an element in `List`